# how to kill asynctask if the task is out of view?

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am displaying images in a **listview** in my app.fetching images from the given **url** is doing by **asynctask**.if i am scrolling my listview fast then my app is crashing becuase many asynctask threads are working parallelly(every images call an asynctask).so i need to **cancell/kill** the threads those are **out of view**.that means only 2-3 asynctask threads can run parallelly(my list can show only 2-3 items at a time).can anybody help me?

Comment: Why it is crashing any exception?

Comment: check your logcat.. what problem is occurring?

Comment: 03-27 11:34:05.705: E/AndroidRuntime(19106): java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: pool=128/128, queue=10/10
this is my logcat error

Comment: nobody has the solution????????? :(

Answer (score 0):

One way is you can buffer all the images to be displayed in your list view and then display. This will improve performance also of your list as whenever you scroll your list, it will download the image from network which is cumbersome. With this, you also don't have to bother about your killing your async tasks for out of view components.

Answer (score 0):

What scenario you are telling you should use `LazyLoading` on your `ListView` and it seems me `OutOfMemory` Error because scrolling too fast cause decode Bitmaps too fast before actually Garbage Collector could take your garbaged `Bitmap`

- https://github.com/cacois/TweetView
- https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-thumbnail/tree

Comment: i have to use asynctask in my app.then how can i solve this issue?

Comment: also can you give complete stacktrace

Answer (score 0):

To me it does not seems an AssynchTask issue it is mostly MemoryIssue if you are decoding your Bitmap using Factory method use this

```
public Bitmap decode(String file, int quality) {
    BitmapFactory.Options o2 = null;
    try {

        BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
        BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, o);

        final int REQUIRED_WIDTH = 240;
        final int REQUIRED_HEIGHT = 280;
        int width_tmp = o.outWidth, height_tmp = o.outHeight;

        int scale = quality;

        scale = quality;
        while (true) {
            if (width_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_WIDTH
                    || height_tmp / 2 < REQUIRED_HEIGHT)
                break;
            width_tmp /= 2;
            height_tmp /= 2;
            scale *= 2;
        }
        o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        o2.inSampleSize = scale;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Decodeing error2", "" + e.getMessage());

    }
    try {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, o2);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.i("Decodeing error1", "" + e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
```

in quality give 4 or 5 in file you can replace it with `InputStream` and also you have to alter some more code to make it useable in your program

Comment: BufferedHttpEntity bufHttpEntity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity()); bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bufHttpEntity.getContent()); this is how i am decoding bitmaps

Comment: Similar Problem as u having http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/6f246c42f5507c16?pli=1

Answer (score 0):

i have find the solution for this issue.i am adding all the asynctask activities to a arraylist. except last 2-3 asynctasks i am killing every elements in that arraylist.code is given below.

```
if(count<maxConst){
                task=new HandleOfferImage();
                offerImageTask.add(task);
                task.execute(obj);
                count++;
            }else{ 
                for(int nCount=0;nCount<offerImageTask.size()-2;nCount++){
                offerImageTask.get(nCount).cancel(true);
                offerImageTask.remove(nCount);

                }
                task=new HandleOfferImage();
                offerImageTask.add(task);
                task.execute(obj);
                count++;
            }
```